# On which atomic factors of the materials does the phenomena of static charge depends?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

Please correct me if I am wrong. Almost all materials are made up of atoms with electrons.

If we rub two different materials, like plastic scale and oily hair on the head, then static charge develops on the surface of scale. This charge can attract tiny bits of paper.
Also during lightening tiny droplets of water and ice crystals rub against each other to create static electricity.

However if I rub my hands on the wall then no static charge develops on the hand. I checked it, as my hand did not attract tiny bits of paper , which means no charge developed on my hand due to rubbing.

My question is : On which atomic factors of the materials does the phenomena of static charge depends ?